# Clickable image that matches screen width and image height

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create some clickable image in android that fills up the width of the screen, but the height of the clickable surface matches the height of the the image itself.

[image: Annoying Extra Space]

I have the following code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:onClick="onClick2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

None of the answers posted so far have helped me, `FitXY` doesn't help as I want to retain aspect ratio. The other answers regarding image button or changing the scale type, give me exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tag needed is `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height = "fill_parent" android:layout_width = "fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" android:id = "@+id/ImageView1"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" android:id = "@+id/ImageView2"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_below = "@+id/ImageView1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forget to set the width of Your image view to match_parent.Also, set the relativeLayout to android:layout_height="match_parent". But it is better to put an ImageButton:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:onClick="onClick2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And You can play a little bit with the scaleTypes (it´s also available at imageView). In the relativeLayout, You have to set for example layout_alignParentTop="true" to set a view to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Make use on linearLayout with vertical orientation

Comment: giving me the same problem

Comment: check the src of the image,there mite be some problem in that

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you can put the image height to `fill_parent` (`match_parent` for API 8 and above) like the following. Then the image has the same height as its parent element.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:onClick="onClick2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is giving me exactly the same problem. I'm trying to support api v7 to v19. `fill_parent` does the same thing for 7 and `match_parent` does the same thing for 8 and up.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to make the parent layout be a LinearLayout and set the height with a defined value, and do it like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

</LinearRelativeLayout>
```

OR

add weight to the imageview itself, but still has a LinearLayout as a parent.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" //This could be like 0.1, 0.7, so long as not 0
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

   </LinearRelativeLayout>
```

Adjusting the weight itself gives you control to the image in a manner of percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ScaleType` of `ImageView` to `centerCrop` or `fitXY`.

```
<ImageView
   android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="onClick2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```